# Metrics on Potential Website Overhaul

Tags: seo, analytics, customer-service, gui, metrics

We are considering a drastic overhaul of our 5+ year old site - UI, structure, content, SEO, backend, etc.  We are not ecommerce, we generate leads for a high cost product.

We're aware of the obvious benefits: better customer service, stronger branding, less bandwidth, etc.

A case is being built to fund this project, so the question at hand: what resources are available that would help us estimate what specific changes would impact a variety of metrics (conversions, leads, etc).  I am looking for general information, not industry specific.

Comment: Do you mean for example, if you changed the logo then you'd get X% more leads?

Comment: That is very simplified, but close.

Answer (score 1):

Wow... can I just say you are looking at this all wrong?

Their is no way someone could say make this change and you will get x result because the whole thing is a totality.  Except speed.  If you increase speed you get an increase.

Having said that, you could work with someone like conversionvoodoo.com to work on the site and say you will get at least a 15% greater conversion rate.

Things that affect the conversion rates:

- design
- ux
- calls to action

Without more specific information, its hard to provide you too much potential detail.

-------------EDIT---------------------

Generic information:

1. [Web Form Conversion Info from Luke W.](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1416)
2. [Steps to Picking the Perfect Number of Landing Page Form Fields](http://camp.hubspot.com/blog/bid/28354/3-Steps-to-Picking-the-Perfect-Number-of-Landing-Page-Form-Fields)
3. [Which Types of of Form Fields Lower Landing Page Conversions](http://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/6746/Which-Types-of-Form-Fields-Lower-Landing-Page-Conversions.aspx) (awesome)
4. [Landing Page Best Practices: Part II](http://www.inboundmarketlink.com/blog-0/bid/50044/Landing-Page-Best-Practices-Part-II)

Comment: Clearly I am looking for generalizations based on aggregated data.  It is very reasonable to expect someone could say "adding video elements increases time on site by 20%" or "sliming down a form to 3 fields increase lead submissions by 2%".  In this case, detail is irrelevant as I'm looking for mass trending actions to help pitch our larger cause.

Comment: Well then your wish is my command.  Hopefully, you find some of this information relevant.  And here is another link that is just good to read about (read the other posts for the whole story) concerning site redesign. - http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2991-behind-the-scenes-ab-testing-part-3-final